# videos do not play when using curl in php

Tags: php, video, curl

For some reason that I don't understand, video websites do not play when using something like this

```
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xn8oqe" );
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)' );
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

can someone please help me understand what needs to be done to have my web server play the video? it seems to load the web-page fine, but the video itself does not play

Comment: You'll need to rewrite the URLs in the embedded player to be non-relative. That's not easy, and it'll be much better to just use their API. More information can be found here: http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/index.html and here: http://www.dailymotion.com/ca-en/doc/api/player

Comment: is this the reason because i tested this with youtube,tudou and other video sharing websites and they all did not load the video, so i assume they all were relative paths?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason. But they all have public APIs, so it's really no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pull a video like that from dailymotion .. The real URL of the video you are about to pull is

http://proxy-42.dailymotion.com/video/074/630/39036470_mp4_h264_aac_hq.mp4?auth=1332377638.11e883c25f004857366fde2e6f9ba4cb&helper=1

Its using an embedded player ... make surre you ready copyright information before you go further

:)

Comment: how did you find that, i don't see that in the source? also the video that is referencing is my own creation, but when i click on your url it says permission denied, so i am at an lost of how to solve this problem

Comment: Yes permission was denied because you are not suppose to access the video directly ... It not a problem .... Its a process & security issue .. have you considered iFrame so that you can html elements can come with it ???

Comment: how would i call the video from there? i need to use this with a cron job, will embedding the video in the Iframe be able to compatible ?

Comment: i am using chrome, i want this script to run server side

Comment: i am using this for the url, so now it is loading, http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xn8oqe&autoStart=1, however it appear the autostart does not work, any enlightenment?

Comment: hey some updates, i manged to get this work browser side, but it does'nt work as a cronjob, any thoughts?